# Cannot load from mysql.proc

Tags: mysql

I can not dump my MySQL-Databeses, however here's the error message:

```
Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
```

Also mysql_upgrade seems not to work:

```
# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

What does that mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to login to MySQL as root, then retry `mysql_upgrade`

[image: parallels] ***Parallels Plesk Panel***:

```
# mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

*Default method*:

```
# mysql_upgrade -u <username> -p <password>
```